# What's the best way to rate limit a spark application

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, rate-limiting

I have an application does the following:

1. Reads URLs from a Hive table
2. Creates HTTP requests from those URLs, hits a server with them and parses the responses
3. Writes the parsed responses to another Hive table

I would like to rate-limit the URLs sent to the server. Currently, to solve the problem I have added a sleep time after every request is sent to the server. The sleep time is calculated as: (no. of executors) * (no. of cores available for each executor) / (RPS intended)

This for some reason does not do any rate limiting, so I am looking for alternatives. From what I have found from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43953882/how-to-rate-limit-a-spark-map-operation), it seems Spark Streaming could be a good alternative if I could use the input Hive table as a streaming source and rate limit the reading.

I have read the documents but can not figure out if a Hive table can be a streaming source. A file can be a streaming source, so I can always read the data from the hive table, store it in a file and then use that as a streaming source but I was wondering if it was possible to avoid this indirect route.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't really using the right tool for the job here.  Yes, spark reads from hive but so do a lot of other tools.  Spark is made to do batch processing, weather it's steaming or processing.  Rate control would require custom code.

You might look at other open source tools, like NIFI that know how to work with hive and also understand hive.  Here's a good discussion on how to control [rate flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46553181/nifi-parallel-and-concurrent-execution-with-executestreamcommand/46553432#46553432) with Nifi.

Or look at [Nutch](https://nutch.apache.org/) which was made to scrape the internet into hadoop.

If you wanted to abuse spark to do this, you might be able to do something with foreachPartitions and repartitioning the partitions up into smaller chunks, and reducing the number of cores/executors, so that the entire job took longer to process... but really your anti-optimizing at that point... again not really a good look.  Possible but not really a good use of Spark.

Comment: Thanks for pointing these libraries out. Will definitely check them out. I had to use Spark because of the platform's limitation that I am working with. Ultimately I "slowed" down the scraping by using asyncio's Semaphore to limit the no. of scraping tasks running at the same time, but I agree that Spark was not the perfect choice.